# try catch with mail problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Lets say I have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(SomeModel m)
{

    try
    {
        _db.SaveModel(m);

        SendMailToUser(m);
        RedirectToRoute("Something");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

And I got problems with howto deal with this if "SendMailToUser" fails. Model gets saved to database. How can I make it continue if the mail fails to send?

/M

Comment: What do you want to happen if the mail sending fails?  Should the error just get ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to swallow the exception (if thrown) from the `SendMailTouser(m)` function you could do:

```
public ActionResult Test(SomeModel m)
{
    try
    {
        _db.SaveModel(m);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }

    try
    {
        SendMailToUser(m);
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        RedirectToRoute("Something");
    }
}
```

If you want to not save the model if the email sending fails, you should wrap the two in a unit-of-work or a transaction block such that it will rollback the Save if the email fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Test(SomeModel m)
{

    try
    {
        _db.SaveModel(m);
        try
        {
            SendMailToUser(m);
        }
        catch
        {
            //do something
        }
        RedirectToRoute("Something");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```